# Configure route metric of tunnel using Netplan

Tags: networking, netplan, routing, rclone

*Under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal*

I previously configured a net64 tunnel to use the HE-IPv6 service. Below is my config:

```
.
├── 50-cloud-init.yaml
└── 51-he-ipv6.yaml

# 50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx
            set-name: ens3
# 51-he-ipv6.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    he-ipv6:
      mode: sit
      remote: 74.xx.xx.xx
      local: 10.0.0.2 
      addresses:
        - "2001:470:xx:xx::x/64"
      gateway6: "2001:470:xx:xx::1"
```

When I use rclone to copy files, I must specify an exit route of 10.0.0.2 otherwise there will be no speed:

```
% rclone copy ...                 # no speed :(
% rclone copy --bind 10.0.0.2 ... # everything work
```

So should I configure route metric for tunnel?If the answer yes, how?

More Informations:

```
% ip route show
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.2 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
xxx.xx.0.0/16 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.2 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-223351777777 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-0ad698888888 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1
% ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000                                                                                                                                     
        inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255                                                                                                                             
        inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>                                                                                                                           
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)                                                                                                                          
he-ipv6: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 8980                                                                                                                                     
        inet6 fe80::a00:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>                                                                                                                                    
        inet6 2001:470:xx:xx:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>                                                                                                                            
        sit  txqueuelen 1000  (IPv6-in-IPv4)
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I added